# Python Tkinter: how to execute caller's methode from a function inside tkinter's ".bind"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making following GUI with Tkinter:

[image]

The numbers are random between 1 and 999 with no duplicate.
The user need to click the button starting from the lowest value up to the highest.

In this case, the sequence is 39>41>242>272>278>337>846>880.

If the user clicks 39, it will be disabled.
If he at the start with other than 39, nothing will happens.
After 39, he could disable 41 by clicking on it and so on...

Now I need a function (click_button) to be called when a button is clicked.
I want to only use a function for all 8 buttons and could not figure out how to make the function to work for all buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Clicker")
items = range(1, 1000)
amount = 8
numbers = random.sample(items, k=amount)
click_sequence = sorted(range(amount), key=numbers.__getitem__)

active_button = tk.IntVar()

button0 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[0], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(0))
button1 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[1], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(1))
button2 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[2], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(2))
button3 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[3], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(3))
button4 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[4], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(4))
button5 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[5], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(5))
button6 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[6], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(6))
button7 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[7], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: active_button.set(7))
                    #command=lambda: print(active_button.get()))

def click_button(*args):
    if active_button.get() == click_sequence[0]:
        click_sequence.pop(0)
        button0.configure(state="disabled")   # Line A

button0.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button2.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button3.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button4.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button5.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button6.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)
button7.bind("<Button-1>", click_button)

button0.grid(column=0, row=0)
button1.grid(column=1, row=0)
button2.grid(column=2, row=0)
button3.grid(column=3, row=0)
button4.grid(column=0, row=1)
button5.grid(column=1, row=1)
button6.grid(column=2, row=1)
button7.grid(column=3, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

As can be seen at "Line A", the function works only for button0.

How could I call the button that call the function "click_button" and disable its state?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't have time to check the codes. I will mark it at the latest tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `binding function` or direct `lambda call` lets use `partial function` from `functools`. Because using this we can use for loop and our `click_button` function parameter will not get override by next iteration and it will create our window easily without writing again and again

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from functools import partial

root = tk.Tk()
items = range(1, 1000)
amount = 8
numbers = random.sample(items, k=amount)
click_sequence = sorted(range(amount), key=numbers.__getitem__)

buttons = {}
def click_button(btn):
    if btn==click_sequence[0]:
        click_sequence.pop(0)
        buttons[btn].configure(state="disabled")

for i in range(8):
    b = tk.Button(root, text=numbers[i],height=4, width=10, command=partial(click_button, i))
    buttons[i] = b 
    if i<4:
        b.grid(column=i, row=0)
    else:
        b.grid(column=7-i, row=1)

print(buttons)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

Modify the command of the buttons as such (you don't need to use an `IntVar` or `bind`)

```py
button0 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[0], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: click_button(0))
button1 = tk.Button(window, text=numbers[1], height=4, width=10,
                    command=lambda: click_button(1))
...
```

Store the buttons in a list

```py
buttons=[button0,button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7]
```

And the function `click_button`

```py
def click_button(btn):
    if btn==click_sequence[0]:
        click_sequence.pop(0)
        buttons[btn].configure(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

I came out with a solution but its somewhat different from yours, it does not use `click_sequence`, instead it uses the sorted array, and then checks if the text of the button is same as the text on the sorted array(in an order).

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Clicker")
items = range(1, 1000)
amount = 8
numbers = random.sample(items, k=amount)
asc_num = sorted(numbers)

idx = 0 # A number to index the ascending list from, which will increase later if correct
def click_button(btn):
    global idx
    if btn.cget('text') == asc_num[new]: # If correct answer 
        btn.config(state="disabled") # Disable the button
        idx += 1 # Increase the index number so next time new number is chosen

btns = [] # List to store the buttons
count = 0 # Number to index the buttons list
for i in range(2): 
    for j in range(4):
        btns.append(tk.Button(window, text=numbers[count], height=4, width=10))
        btns[-1]['command'] = lambda btn=btns[count]: click_button(btn) # Splitting because too long for one line ;)
        btns[count].grid(row=i,column=j) # Gridding 
        
        count += 1 # Increase the number by 1

window.mainloop()
```

I have also reduced defining functions in one by one, as you could easily just loop through them and create buttons, but its important to keep a reference to these buttons so you can reuse them later, so store them inside a list(`btns`).

Since your buttons are placed in a 4x2 grid manner, the looping is done in 4 rows and 2 columns. The function checks if the text on button and a indexed number on list is equal, if yes, the index number is increased(`idx+=1`).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I also like yours, which uses another strategy (asc_num). I spent a lot of time to come up with my "click_sequence". But I think yours is more elegant.